# How can I attach two Suffix Icon Button on TextFormField in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want this:

[image]

but I can't implement it.

I tried:

```
TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: Strings.AuthPage.PASSWORD,
            hasFloatingPlaceholder: true,
            suffixIcon: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
            ),
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(snapshot.data ? Icons.visibility : Icons.visibility_off),
                  onPressed: _authBloc.switchObscureTextMode,
                ),
              ],
            ),
        ),
        controller: passwordController,
        obscureText: snapshot.data,
      ),
```

But the result was as follows:

[image]

[image: Third screenshot.]

So, How can I attach two Suffix Icon Button on TextFormField in Flutter?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You have to use Property of Row Widget To achieve your desire output.

```
TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: Strings.AuthPage.PASSWORD,
              hasFloatingPlaceholder: true,
              suffixIcon: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, // added line
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, // added line
                children: <Widget>[
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(snapshot.data
                        ? Icons.visibility
                        : Icons.visibility_off),
                    onPressed: _authBloc.switchObscureTextMode,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            controller: passwordController,
            obscureText: snapshot.data,
          ),
```

Comment: The key here is the `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min` which shrinks the Row to it's smallest size possible so the text will still be visible. Great Answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
     decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                              color: Colors.red),
                                          borderRadius:
                                              const BorderRadius.all(
                                                  Radius.circular(10))),
                                      labelText: "Confirm password",
                                      suffixIcon: IconButton(
                                        splashColor: Colors.transparent,
                                        highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                                        icon: Icon(
                                          !controller.isObscureConfirm.value
                                              ? Icons.visibility_outlined
                                              : Icons.visibility_off_outlined,
                                          size: 26,
                                          color: ColorConstants.grayLight,
                                        ),
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          controller.isObscureConfirm.value =
                                              !controller
                                                  .isObscureConfirm.value;
                                        },
                                      ),
                                    ),
```

// change to :

Comment: The question is about showing two icons as part of suffix. Your answer is only good for showing one icon with the obscure feature. Please try to go through the entire question and provide the desired solution. Thank you